# IE7 Bug - the main-box moves to the left on hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to fix this issue in IE7 that when you hover on it it won't remain in its position but will go to the left side. I've tried display:inline but it won't work in this case.
 You can test it here: http://www.sneakyrascal.com/kayak/results.html 
This is the code I am using for the main-box(the middle one):

```
.results #container{ 
    float:left;
    width: 527px;
    margin:38px 0 0 20px;
    padding-left:1px;
    position: relative;
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's more to this - do you have any elements inside the container with :hover styles assigned?

Comment: Yeah - you need to provide us with the `__:hover` elements that may be affecting your element. **Also**, please provide some more insight into your issue - *what* is moving when hovered?

Comment: There is no :hover it's a common bug! As I mentioned the middle box moves to the left. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by `position:relative` on `#main-content`. If you remove it the container will not jump any more:

```
#main-content {
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative; /* delete this */
}
```

Also you might have noticed that your `.sites` div was not lining up properly. Adding `left: 0` will fix that:

```
.results #container UL LI.box .left-side .sites{
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: I removed it and it works. Thank you. Also about the .sites I set margin for IE7 only so it would look the same as it is with the other browsers but the way you explained is the semantic way. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: oh god, thank u! xD i have same bug and i was hopeless. stupid ies... :))

Answer (score 3):

Huhh, weird bug, you can fix it by properly containing your #main-content id. Just add this to it:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm sure it will be helpful for the future bugs with IE.